# Silly error in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a jquery code

```
$(function(){
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-icon', 
        build: function($trigger, e) {
            // this callback is executed every time the menu is to be shown
            // its results are destroyed every time the menu is hidden
            // e is the original contextmenu event, containing e.pageX and e.pageY (amongst other data)
            return {
                callback: function(key, options) 
                {
                    if(key=='delete')
                        $(this).remove();
                },
                items: {
                    "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
                    "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
                    "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
                    "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
                    "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
                    "sep1": "---------",
                    "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: "quit"}
                }
            };
        }
    });
});
```

In the line, 
   `selector: '.context-menu-icon',`
i want to put two classes as selector

so i made it like this

`selector: {'.context-menu-icon','context-menu-text'},`

but dont know why, its not working..

Any suggestions

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Is it this one? http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html

Comment: yes, that the plugin i am using

Comment: `{'.context-menu-icon','context-menu-text'}` is a syntax error. Drop the `{}`.

Comment: isn't context-menu-text a class ? shouldn't it be '.context-menu-text'  notice the forgotten dot ! $('.context-menu-icon, .context-menu-text')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you use [this](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html) plugin, have you tried modifying your code like:

```
$(function(){
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-icon, .context-menu-text', 
        build: function($trigger, e) {
            // this callback is executed every time the menu is to be shown
            // its results are destroyed every time the menu is hidden
            // e is the original contextmenu event, containing e.pageX and e.pageY (amongst other data)
            return {
                callback: function(key, options) 
                {
                    if(key=='delete')
                        $(this).remove();
                },
                items: {
                    "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
                    "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
                    "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
                    "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
                    "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
                    "sep1": "---------",
                    "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: "quit"}
                }
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Note: It's untested, but according to the documention, I think it should work.

Comment: yes, you are right bro... i tested the code with the changes u recommended and its working fine.. Thanks

Comment: I will give u the answer as marked... one other guy also gave the right answer, but since u have much less points, i think u need it more...

Comment: That's kind of you, the other person was first, that's true, but I just gave a bit more of explanation. Anyway, award the points to the person that deserves it according to you. Don't want to push you.

Answer (score 2):

The `selector` property in that plugin is a string, yet you are trying to use an object.

Just use the comma (see [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)) to separate them both within the selector:

```
selector: '.context-menu-icon, .context-menu-text'
```

Comment: yes, you are right... i tested the code with the changes u recommended and its working fine.. Thanks